# Trying to download a .gz file using NodeJS/Typescript and the file downloads as 'either in unknown format or damaged'

Tags: node.js, gzip

So I'm writing a service where I have to download some .gz file, exctract the .xml file inside, get the data I need and delete them. However, when I try to download using the code below I'm getting nowhere because the file I'm downloading is 'either in unknown format or damaged'. I tried different ways to download the file but always the same problem.

example url:

```
http://matrixcatalog.co.il/CompetitionRegulationsFiles/latest/7290661400001/PriceFull7290661400001-097-202307220359-001.xml.gz
```

example: filePath: `./data/file.xml.gz`

code:

```
async function downloadFile(url: string, filePath: string): Promise<void> {
  const response = await axios.get(url, {
    responseType: 'stream',
    headers: {
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
    },
  });

  const writer = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
  response.data.pipe(writer);

  return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    writer.on('finish', resolve);
    writer.on('error', reject);
  });
}
```

I did try downloading the file manually using the browser and that way everything works fine so the file isn't the problem here. If any of you guys have experience in this area I would love some help. Thank you.

Comment: The "accept-encoding" won't automatically decompress it, because it is not encoded on the server side in the first place. It is simply a file being downloaded that happens to be in gzip format. You need to decompress it with the [Python gzip library](http://matrixcatalog.co.il/CompetitionRegulationsFiles/latest/7290661400001/PriceFull7290661400001-097-202307220359-001.xml.gz).

Answer (score 0):

In your current implementation, axios might not be handling the decompression properly, resulting in a damaged or unknown format file.
You can try this work around to see if it works in your case

```js
     return axios.get(url, { headers: { Accept: 'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding': 'identity' }, params: { trophies: true } })
```

Here's a [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) link and here's a [github](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5298) link wehre I got it from.
Alternatively you can try the 'zlib' module. Implementation will be something like this,

```
import axios from 'axios'
import fs from 'fs'
import zlib from 'zlib'

async function downloadFile(url: string, filePath: string): Promise<void> {
  const response = await axios.get(url, {
    responseType: 'stream',
    headers: {
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
    },
  });

  const writer = fs.createWriteStream(filePath)

  const unzip = zlib.createGunzip() // Create the gunzip stream

  response.data.pipe(unzip).pipe(writer) // Pipe the response through the gunzip stream to the writer

  return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    writer.on('finish', resolve)
    writer.on('error', reject)
  })
}
```